# Excel Changing Variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

consider that i have data in excel (B1=2, B2=5, B3=7, ... ) and ( A1=2 , A2=3)

i want to make a formula in C1 = B(A1) + B(A2) whitch result in 12 for this case

i tried B$A1 and B[A1] and B"A1" and   ...  all other things, not any chance
can you help me

hello
consider that i have data in excel (B1=2, B2=5, B3=7, ... ) and ( A1=2 , A2=3)

i want to make a formula in C1 = B(A1) + B(A2) whitch result in 12 for this case

i tried B$A1 and B[A1] and B"A1" and   ...  all other things, not any chance
can you help me

Comment: How `B(A1) + B(A2)=12`? Can you please explain logic?

Comment: no no i want to do somthing like this in excel

Comment: `=INDEX(B:B,A1)+INDEX(B:B,A2)` I think is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXCEL-365` try-

```
=SUM(INDEX(B1:B3,A1:A2))
```

[image]